# wordpress shortcode with variables as parameters

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

I have this shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcode_name', 'netoResultText');
```

the start of the "netoResultText" callback function is like this:

```
 function netoResultText($attr) {   

     $params = shortcode_atts( array(
               'broto_price' => '10000',
               'discount_points' => '2.25',
               'is_deposit_found' => 'true'
     ), $attr ); 

     --- code for calculating price ---

  }
```

I use  - code snippets plugin - to create this shortcode.

I have a Js function that creates Html as a response to a click event:

```
 let netoResultText = `[shortcode_name broto_price=${brotoPrice.valueOf()}  discount_points= ${discountPoints.valueOf()} is_deposit_found= ${isdepositFound.valueOf()}]`;

      jQuery("#netoResult").append("<p>" + netoResultText + "</p>");
      jQuery("#netoResult").show();
```

in the "netoResultText" var I try to create the shortcode and pass to it parameters dynamically.

then I am appending it to #netoResult to show the result of the shortcode.

the problem is that it doesn't work with variables. using backtick was my last try to pass those

parameters.  if I hard-code the parameters like this

```
"[shortcode_name broto_price=7500  discount_points=5.5  is_deposit_found=true]";
```

all Is good and I get the shortcode results, but if I use variables the parameters don't get transferred

and I am getting only the default numbers of the parameters.

How can I pass variables to my shortcode?

Comment: A shortcode fn substitutes the shortcode text/html with the result of the shortcode function.  The result is the html you will see if you 'view source'.  The square bracket shortcode text no longer exists once the page is served up.   

If you want to adjust the shortcode function parameters at html rendering time, then you need to include those variables in the shortcode php function and not in the editor text.   EG: it might check for logged in user and use a different discount.

Javascript cannot affect the shortcode execution.  It is too late.

Comment: I create the shortcode by Js it is not hard-coded in the Html.
meaning when the page is served there is no shortcode at all, 
afterwords I push a button and create the shortcode fn via Js.
It works when I Use hard coded values but not when I use variables WHY ?

Comment: What is appearing in the hml after you click the button?

Comment: Ben S - why are using the shortcode structure at all?  It doesn't sound like it is a 'shortcode' in the wordpress sense.  This is fetching the data & updating html when a button is pushed.  Sounds more like ajax.  See https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/submitting-forms-without-reloading-ajax-implementation-wordpress/ and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313643/how-to-call-a-php-function-with-ajax-when-the-user-clicks-a-button

Comment: @anmari you are correct I used ajax and it worked. add an action not a shortcode
thanks